# Vokoscreen Not Working On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, screencast

I been trying to make it work on Ubuntu 14.04, but no luck . How do I fix the error ?

[image]

> Full Logs Starting VokoScreen From Terminal

```
vokoscreen 

[vokoscreen] Locale: "en_US" 
[vokoscreen] Version: "1.9.0" 
[vokoscreen] Qt Version:  4.8.6 
[vokoscreen] asoundlib Version: "1.0.27.2" 

[vokoscreen] ---Begin Search external tools--- 
[vokoscreen] "/usr/bin/ffmpeg" is a link and pointing to "/opt/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg" 
[vokoscreen] Find pactl 
[vokoscreen] Find mkvmerge 
[vokoscreen] ---End search external tools--- 

[vokoscreen] ---Begin search Videoplayer--- 
[vokoscreen] Find Videoplayer : "/usr/bin/avplay" 
[vokoscreen] Find Videoplayer : "/usr/bin/ffplay" 
[vokoscreen] Find Videoplayer : "/usr/bin/smplayer" 
[vokoscreen] Find Videoplayer : "/usr/bin/totem" 
[vokoscreen] Find Videoplayer : "/usr/bin/vlc" 
[vokoscreen] ---End search Videoplayer--- 

[vokoscreen][Regional selection] Frame locked: false 

[vokoscreen] ---Begin search PulseAudio Plugin--- 
[vokoscreen] Found file .asound for PulseAudio Plugin 
[vokoscreen] ---End search PulseAudio Plugin--- 


[vokoscreen] ---Begin Pulse unload Module--- 
[vokoscreen] ---End Pulse unload Module--- 

[vokoscreen] ---Begin search Alsa capture device--- 
[vokoscreen] alsa_device_sample() in alsadevice.c: open audio device hw:0,0 (Success)
[vokoscreen] alsa_device_sample() in alsadevice.c: Samplerate = 44100
[vokoscreen] Find CaptureCard: "[hw:0,0] HDA Intel PCH" 
[vokoscreen] alsa_device_sample() in alsadevice.c: cannot open audio device hw:1,3 (No such file or directory)
[vokoscreen] Find CaptureCard: "[hw:1,3] HDA NVidia" 
[vokoscreen] ---End search Alsa capture device--- 

[vokoscreen] ---Begin search PulseAudio Capture Devices--- 
[vokoscreen] Find CaptureCard: "Monitor of GF108 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)" with device: "alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor" 
[vokoscreen] Find CaptureCard: "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" with device: "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor" 
[vokoscreen] Find CaptureCard: "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo" with device: "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo" 
[vokoscreen] ---End search PulseAudio Capture Devices--- 

[vokoscreen] ffmpegcommand : " -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1366x768 -i :0.0+0,0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mpeg4 -ar 48000 -qscale 1 -r 25 /tmp/vokoscreen-vokoscreen/vokoscreen-2014-05-03_22-09-34.mkv" 

[vokoscreen] ffmpeg is not running 
[vokoscreen][Regional selection] Frame locked: false 

The process could not be started. Either the is called program is not installed, or the ffmpeg or avconv call Faulty or you have not over sufficient permissions to to the program.
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @Mitch sudo apt-get install vokoscreen

Comment: I just installed fro USC, and it works OK.

Comment: But not here ......@Mitch

Answer (score 1):

Probably it calls `ffmpeg` instead of `avconv`

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/avconv /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/avconv /usr/bin/ffmpeg = ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/ffmpeg’: File exists

Comment: first do `sudo mv /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg_backup`

Comment: same error ......@Cornelius

Comment: @Qasim `sudo rm /usr/bin/ffmpeg` and after that try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/avconv /usr/bin/ffmpeg` again

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 works with avconv, not with ffmpeg.
Delete ffmpeg. Delete vokoscreen and reinstall again.